# SAPUI5 - Apply Initial Sort for SmartTable

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing a SAPUI5 application and having some problems to set a initial Sort for a SmartTable. Tryed this [Sapui5: How can I set an initial sort order in smarttable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868667/sapui5-how-can-i-set-an-initial-sort-order-in-smarttable) but not worked.

My code:
View

```
<smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="CustomerOrders" id="tbOrders" tableType="Table" useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport"
            header="Ordens de Manutenção" showRowCount="true" enableAutoBinding="true" beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable"
            initiallyVisibleFields="PriorityName,OrderTypeType,OrderTypeName,Id,DateOpen,HourOpen,BrandName,EquipmentId,EquipmentNumber,SymptomName"
            class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
```

Controller:

```
onBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
var oSmartTable = oEvent.getSource();
if (this._isOnInit == null) this._isOnInit = true; //To set this initial sorter only when view start
if (this._isOnInit) {
    oSmartTable.applyVariant({
        sort: {
            sortItems: [{
                    columnKey: "PriorityName",
                    operation: "Ascending"
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    this._isOnInit = false;
}
```

But the sortering is only applied visually like these images.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f55dh.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMP14.png)

The correct order is like this.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjlGQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [API documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/events/beforeRebindTable)
The easiest way is to modify the "sorter" array, coming inside "oEvent" parameter in the "beforeRebindTable" hook.

This approach is more lightweight and stable. "ApplyVariant" was designed to cover a bit different scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now i added my method is like this and working 100%.
`var oParameters = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
oParameters.sorter = [new sap.ui.model.Sorter("DateOpen", false),new sap.ui.model.Sorter("PriorityId", false),new sap.ui.model.Sorter("HourOpen", false)]'